# Messed up recursion code for a board game

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

What I have to do here is to count the number of adjacent white blocks (in 2's) on a square board which is made up of random black(0's) and white(1's) blocks. The white blocks have to be at `i+1,j` || `i-1,j` || `i,j+1` || `i,j-1`. Technically diagonals are not counted. I have provided an example below:

```
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
```

Here `count == 3` `(0,0)(1,0) and (1,0)(1,1) and (1,1)(2,1)`

Here is my code:

```
public int count = 0;
    boolean count(int x, int y, int[][] mat)
    {
        if(x<0 || y<0)
            return false;
        if(mat[x][y] == 0)
            return false;

        for(int i = x; i<mat.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = y; j<mat[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(mat[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                    if(count(i-1,j,mat))
                        count++;
                    if(count(i,j-1,mat))
                        count++;
                    if(count(i+1,j,mat))
                        count++;
                    if(count(i,j+1,mat))
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Short explanation of what I am trying to do here: I am going about finding 1's on the board and when I find one I change it to a 0 and check its up,down,left,right for a 1. This goes on till I find no adjacent 1's. What is the thing I am missing here? I kind of have a feeling I am looping unnecessarily.

Comment: do you have to use recursion?

Comment: This is not homework, nor do I have to use recursion. I just thought of it. If there is a better solution, I'd love to know.

Comment: I would recommend using a loop. at each cell with a 1 check the cell below and to the right of it for a 1. Don't check the cells above or to the left to avoid counting matches you already have.

Comment: Also you should be using `mat[i].length` in the inner loop not `mat[0].length` so you are checking the current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a solution without recursion

```
for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
       if(mat[i][j] == 1) {
          if(i < mat.length - 1 && mat[i+1][j] == 1) {
              count++;
          }
          if(j < mat[i].length - 1 && mat[i][j+1] == 1) {
              count++;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think recursion is the right answer as you should only being going one step deep (to find the adjacent value). Instead just loop through the elements looking to the right and down. Don't look up or left as twain mentioned so that you don't double count matches. Then is it simply:

```
for (i=0; i<max; i++)
  for (j=0; j<max; j++)
    if (array[i][j] == 1){
         if (i<max-1 && array[i+1][j] == 1) count++;
         if (j<max-1 && array[i][j+1] == 1) count++;
    }
```